Regex to match the next closing bracket of the same pair
Document
The document I'm matching came from Steam's localconfig.vdf, after simplifying, it looks like follow:
"apps"
{
    "1162520"
    {
        "LastPlayed"        "1625669107"
        "Playtime"      "879"
    }
    "1172470"
    {
        "LastPlayed"        "1724604465"
        "Playtime2wks"      "1523"
        "Playtime"      "120319"
        "1172470_eula_1"        "1"
        "cloud"
        {
            "last_sync_state"       "synchronized"
        }
        "LaunchOptions"     "+cl_showfps 4 +cl_showpos 1 -high -dev -forcenovsync"
        "BadgeData"     "020000000803"
    }
    "760"
    {
        "cloud"
        {
            "quota_bytes"       "20000000000"
            "quota_files"       "50000"
            "used_bytes"        "0"
            "used_files"        "0"
        }
    }
    "2371090"
    {
        "cloud"
        {
            "last_sync_state"       "synchronized"
        }
    }
}

Goal
I want to retrieve game datas, for example:
example 1
"1172470"
{
    "LastPlayed"        "1724604465"
    "Playtime2wks"      "1523"
    "Playtime"      "120319"
    "1172470_eula_1"        "1"
    "cloud"
    {
        "last_sync_state"       "synchronized"
    }
    "LaunchOptions"     "+cl_showfps 4 +cl_showpos 1 -high -dev -forcenovsync"
    "BadgeData"     "020000000803"
}

example 2
"1162520"
{
    "LastPlayed"        "1625669107"
    "Playtime"      "879"
}

example 3
"2371090"
{
    "cloud"
    {
        "last_sync_state"       "synchronized"
    }
}

What I have now
Currently I'm able to match the starts of the game data using: "1172470"[\n\r\s]+\{, with 1172470 part change to other game-id.
The Problem
Looking at the data of 1172470 / 760 / 2371090, they both have a second layer data, therefore my question is: How can I use a regex to match the paired closing bracket? and get the whole part of the game data string.

Please mention your regex flavor along with such question (recursive regex). In PCRE you could use something like "1172470"\s*({(?:[^}{]*(?1)?)*}) (note that \s already contains \n & \r)

the vdf format seems fairly complicated. For example // ... is a comment - and so {/} inside should be ignored; #include syntax is allowed. instead of regex, consider using a purpose built parser. for example, a quick search on github finds https://github.com/ValvePython/vdf and https://github.com/p0358/vdf-parser

I've made a regex that works on 2 layers data, but I'd be greatful if anyone can provide a version that can recursively match n-layers.
"1172470"[\n\r\s]*\{([^\{\}]|(\{[^\{\}]*\}))*\}

"1172470"
match the game id

[\n\r\s]*
match the line-break or any spaces after the game id

\{
match the starting bracket of the game data

(\n|[^\{\}]|(\{([^\{\}]|\n|)*\}))* match the following cases:

[^\{\}] include anything that's not brackets
(\{[^\{\}]*\}) try to match if there's any layer-2 data (not recursive, only match second layer)


\}
match the ending bracket of the game data


